# load balancer between dyndns hosts

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, router, dyndns

I have

- Two routers connected to the Internet, to know their addresses I use the DynDNS service
- An address, example: www.company.com,
- Routers use NAT to connect with the application on different hosts (LAN).
- On each host Nginx server

I want that when someone tries to connect to the www.company.com address the request is redirected to the address and port of the router with less workload or active connections.

What services I would need to hire or install to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: "What services I would need to hire or install to achieve it?" Step one? Get static IPs. For many reasons, dynamic IPs are not suited for situations like this.

Comment: My provider does not supply fiber optic static IPs

Comment: But if I had static IPs how to proceed